# PHP fix numeric keys in array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

For some reason when removing items from an array I am left with keys like 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9 instead of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. So I am trying to figure out why, and what I can do to fix it without sorting everything via `sort()` as that will put stuff in order. I just want to re-key in a matter of speaking.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [`array_values()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to get the values of the original array and return them to a new array. That new array will contain new numerical keys.

```
$new_array = array_values($old_array);
```

Comment: I have to assume this doesn't work when an array key can potentially be associative, and you want to know about thouse.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `array_splice()` to remove elements from your array so it changes the key the way you wish at the same time.

You have to be careful with `array_values()` since it will not (or at least might not) work, because it may [re-order your numeric indexes](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-values.php#114941). If you added the value at index 0 after the value at index 3, the value at index 0 will be placed at the end of the array returned by `array_values()`, while it appears first in yours.

Answer (score 3):

Since the keys don't necessarily matter, you can just run your final result array through [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values). It leaves all the values in the order they already were, resetting all the keys to sequential numeric values.

Comment: It's actually false, someone found out that the order is not the order of appearance but the foreach order that is preservered: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-values.php#114941